# Method of Undetermined Coefficients - Differential Ecuations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving the following differential ecuation:

$y^{(4)} - y''' = 2 - x^2e^x$

Is the form of the particular solution:

$y_p= Ax^3 + (Bx^2 + Cx)e^x$

If not, can you give any advice in how to visualize better this kind of problems?

Thanks in advance.

*Edited: i was missing an ' character *

*Edit no.2*

Solution:

$y_c = C_1 + {C_2}x + {C_3}x^2 + {C_4}e^x$

$y_p = Ax^3 + (Bx^3 + Cx^2 + Dx)e^x$

solving $y_p$ we have

$y = C_1 + {C_2}x + {C_3}x^2 - \frac{1}{3}x^3 + (C_4 -\frac{1}{3}x^3 + 3x^2 -12x)e^x $

Comment: How does your equation look correctly?

Comment: I believe another user has edited so it can look correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did fine with the first term. But you also need to apply the "resonance" to the second term. As the root 1 has multiplicity one on the left side, you get $x^1q_2(x)e^x$ where $q_2$ is a quadratic polynomial with full coefficient set to determine. Just like in the first term where the multiplicity of the root/exponential factor $0$ is three, so you correctly got $x^3q_1(x)e^{0x}$ and $q_1(x)$ is a constant polynomial.